# About an argument in absolute prismatic cohomology

Tags: derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, crystalline-cohomology

In Bhatt-Lurie [*Absolute prismatic cohomology*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.06120v1), proof of Corollary 4.1.15, it asserts that extension of scalars along the quotient map is conservative and preserves small limits:
[image]
I think the conservativity uses the [derived Nakayama](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0G1U), but in derived Nakayama, the target is the uncompleted category, while Bhatt-Lurie's proof uses completed one (completion is not conservative in general). Is it automatically $p$-complete? And how to see it preserves small limits?

More generally, if $I, J\subset A$ are finitely generated ideals, $M\in{\rm D}(A)$ is $(I+J)$-complete, then is $M\otimes_A^{\bf L}A/I\in{\rm D}(A/I)$ automatically $J$-complete?

Comment: In Lurie's [SAG, Corollary 7.3.3.4], it says that a limit-preserving functor preserves complete objects (apply to the ideal $I+J$, with [SAG, Corollary 7.3.3.6]).

Comment: I am not sure about the general statement that you proposed, but in the special case that $I\to A$ is an invertible (quasi-)ideal, this is the case, since $M\otimes_{A}^L(A/I)=\operatorname{cofib}(M\to M\otimes_A^LI)$, and both $M\mapsto M$ and $M\mapsto M\otimes_A^LI$, as functors $\mathcal D(A)\to\mathcal D(A)$, preserve small limits, where the later uses the dualizability of $I\in\mathcal D(A)$ (in fact, when $I$ is invertible, this functor is an equivalence).

Comment: @Z. M I think the arrow in the cofib should be in opposite direction. Do you use something like cofib preserves small limits (and why)?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. And yes, because small limits are exact functors, thus preserve finite colimits (in this special case, it is just a shift of fiber, thus commutes with small limits).

Comment: I see, thanks! I think the general statement can be treated similarly, if we interpret the quotient $A/I$ in the derived sense (not literally), then it will be an iterated shift of fibers.

Comment: You cannot do that. There is no intrinsic "derived sense" of $A/I$ other than $A/I$ itself. You might want to say choosing generators of $I$ and taking the derived quotient, but this depends on the chosen generators (not just on $I$).

Comment: Yeah, I saw Kęstutis-Scholze *Purity for flat cohomology* defines a derived quotient $A/^{\bf L}I$ using generators, but not sure in what sense it is well-behaved.